# object in Single vert doesn't have vertex in edit mode

Tags: modeling, objects, add-on, edit-mode, vertices

When I added single vert like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuDT9N3ka0A&t=147s
, but my object didn't have any vertex like he had in the video in min 1:47 [image]

Comment: You need to enable X-Ray mode to see the vertex in edit mode. It's is inside the skin mesh. Look at the blue buttons in the top right corner of the interface

Comment: I tried it, it's still the same.

Comment: are you in vertex selection mode when you go to `Edit Mode`?

Comment: @aliasguru No the problem is with the single vertex. when i add single vertex the object doesn't have any vertex except 2.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your vertex is too small to see.Pls go to Preferences-Themes-3D Viewport to change the size of vertex.

Comment: i also tried that and there's only two vertex in the object